# Can we make txs free of cost/without staking on privately deployed eos network

Tags: transactions, eosio-code, eosio.system, private-blockchain

I want to deploy a private eos network on which users don't have to stake or pay ram or network or cpu is that possible if yes how so ? do I have to tweak code in eosio.system contracts 
Also what are risks involved in doing so i mean would that be architecturally right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources are managed by eosio.system contract, so if you don't deploy eosio.system to eosio account, there is no limitations on sending transactions.

For example, you can run single-node local testnet like this:

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin
```

After launching single-node local testnet, create account by the next command:

```
cleos create account eosio YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

You can see all resources such as CPU, NET bandwidth and RAM are unlimited.

```
cleos get account YOUR_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

A limitation on resource makes blockchain secure. For example, in above single-node local testnet, user can send transactions infinitely (Unlimited CPU/NET), it can be a point of DOS (Denial-Of-Service) attack. Moreover, when network is congested, CPU and NET set priorities among transactions, so block producers can determine which transaction should be processed first.

Comment: how to can we regproducer without system contract can we ?

Comment: also are the accounts created with cleos create account command and function newaccount (https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/f6578c45c83ec60826e6a1eeb9ee71de85abe976/contracts/eosio.system/src/eosio.system.cpp#L322) basically same or not ?

Comment: Use `eosio.bios` contract instead of `eosio.system`. `cleos create account` only calls `newaccount`, but `cleos system newaccount` will send a transaction consisting of 3 actions, `newaccount`, `delegatebw` (for CPU/NET staking) and `buyram`.